# SAML service provider signature verification

Tags: security, single-sign-on, saml, pingfederate

This is a basic question about SAML protocol and how it specifies verification of a SAML token.

Looking an different diagrams and resources, it looks like the service provider doesn't need to make calls to the Identity Provider (IdP) in order to verify a SAML token.
I am interested in clarifying step 5 (Request the Assertion Consumer Service at the SP) from wiki[SAMPL_wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language).
Mainly token verification is done on Service Provider without additional calls to IdP. 
Token validation consists of the 3 steps:
1.Verify token is well-formed
2.Verify token is coming from the intended authority
3.Verify token is meant for the current application

Is this assumption right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a very high level, yes, your three steps are correct.

More specific:

1 will include decoding the base64 encoded response, checking against
    schema, etc.

2 will be done via signature validation, checking the authority,
    seeing if it's a response to a sent AuthnRequest and matching it,
    etc.

3 comes from checking the relay state and ensuring that it is a
    location that is "protected" by the service provider